# Nginx with www and without www

Tags: nginx, centos6

I have a server directive with nginx:

```
    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name mydomain.net;
            root /home/sites/mydomain.net;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
                    include         fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/sites/mydomain.net$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_index   index.php;
            }
}
```

This works great when I access mydomain.net. But nothing here says to apply the stuff if the user tries www.mydomain.net

The searching I have done shows people having a whole other directive listening with a server_name www.mydomain.net, which seems.. not great. e.g.

```
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name www.mydomain.net;
            root /home/sites/mydomain.net;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
                    include         fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/sites/mydomain.net$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_index   index.php;
            }
}
```

Basically doubling the config code. Or otherwise doing a rewrite.

Is there an lesser way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use multiple names in `server_name` and even repeat it.

For instance, to answer to three hostnames, you could do something like:

```
server {
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        server_name api.example.com;
```

Comment: unbelievably simple.

Comment: thanks again - seemed I could only find rewrite examples everywhere.